# Why are aliases not resolved correctly with my config?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

I have a following `resolve` option in my webpack config:

```
resolve: {
    modules: ["./app/static/js/homepage/", "./app/static/js/dashboard/",],
    extensions: [".js", ],
    alias: {
        "bootstrap": "../../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap",
        "lodash": "../../bower_components/lodash/lodash",
    // ...
```

But i get this error:

```
ERROR in ./app/static/js/dashboard/main.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'underscore' in '/app/app/static/js/dashboard'
 @ ./app/static/js/dashboard/main.js 84:0-112:2
```

Which means it doesn't treat `underscore` as an alias, which happens to all `define`s in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are aliasing them to a relative path and you go up two directories (with `../../`), so when you import lodash in`./app/static/js/dashboard/main.js`, it will try to find the module in

```
./app/static/bower_components/lodash/lodash
```

Assuming that your `bower_components` are in the top level of the project (as it is recommended), you can fix the aliases by going up four directories:

```
alias: {
  "bootstrap": "../../../../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap",
  "lodash": "../../../../bower_components/lodash/lodash",
}
```

*Note, this will only work if you import them in a file that is four levels deep*. Replacing them with absolute paths would work everywhere.

An even cleaner solution is to add `bower_components` to  your modules, so it looks in every `bower_component` directory, which is the common way to integrate bower into webpack. With that you could just use `import _ from 'lodash/lodash'` without adding any aliases. But if you'd still like to have an alias you could do it as follows:

```
resolve: {
  modules: ["bower_components"],
  extensions: [".js"],
  alias: {
    "bootstrap": "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap",
    "lodash": "lodash/lodash",
  }
}
```

Comment: Adding `bower_componenets` to modules fixed it. I was sure that my paths were correct for some reason =)